# Animation is exported, but does not appear along with the mesh of the object

Tags: animation, export, unreal-engine

**I did what was done in this video:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWKOOoSKFK8

In the video is basically made 5 identical cubes, one on top of each other, and each with a bone.

**Result:**

[image]

**In the video is also made an animation with the object. Similar to the movement of a tentacle or gasoline doll:**

[image]

**Object already in the Unreal 4:**

[image]

**I only have problem in the animation, no mesh appears:**

[image]

**Note that bone animation happens, but no mesh appears:**

[image]

**And also from what I understand, all bones are in the same place (paused animation):**

[image]

**Disabling this option, I could see the mesh in the animation:**

[image]

**However the animation does not happen and the bones are now not in the same place, but some are still not in the right position:**

[image]

**Warning that appears in the case where I can't see the mesh, but the bones move and are in the same place:**

[image]

**Warning that appears in the case where I can see the mesh, the bones are in different locations, but not completely correct and do not move:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When exporting from Blender to UE4, the set origin coordinate must be at position 0.0.0. Both the object and bone must have origin set at the same coordinate.
See the reference image and you will understand.

[blender 2.81 to ue4](https://youtu.be/ENqvKrdFbZk)

fbx export scale 0.1 or 0.01 or 1

UE4 import scale 1 or 10 or 100

[image: ex image]

Comment: I updated both programs (Blender and Unreal) to their latest versions. Your video helped me a lot! I saw it completely and I modified the scales just as you did, making the export to the program work completely.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still after an answer, I have found a few different soloutions to various Blender>Unreal problems that when I combine, seem to work. Could be one of these:

- Don't have fullstops in your bone names
- Rename your Armature to anything else
- Don't call your root bone 'Spine' (You've not done this. Could jut need to be carful eitheir way.)

Not sure if any of these help this particular issue, as mine is usually just everything importing microscopic.